# My 2000 Chevy impala won't start

Tags: battery, troubleshooting, starter, jump-start

At first when I tried to start it the lights came on and the check engine light came on but no start. Now I get no reaction at all. Need help

Answer (score 2):

No start is classified into two categories, cranking and non cranking.

Cranking is when you hear the engine turning over but not starting. Where the fault would be in your ignition system. If this is the case check:

```
- spark plugs
- wires
- distributor (if applicable)
- Ignition coil
- Starter
```

If there is a no cranking, that means there is a fault in the charging system check:

```
  - Battery 
  - Battery Terminals + Wires 
  - Starter 
  - Alternator
```